# Track activities in multiple Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I am in charge of 10 Excel files in Shared folder. And I am very curious, who is viewing my files, what sheets exactly they are looking at and in what time frame. Is there any possibility to track this activities, please? I am just thinking about that it would be possible to create one extra file with VBA code connected to all of those 10 excel files and somehow extract the data. However, I do not know how to start.

Thanks.

Comment: You could create event procedures that writes a log of all you mention. The log would be in a TXT file. The workbook would become a macro-enabled one (XLSM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code for all 10 excel files. Whenever any file is opening following code will get executed and write the data to Monitor file.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim LR As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        file_name = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        open_time = Time
        user_name = Environ("UserName")
    End With
    Set targetwb = Workbooks.Open("D:\Test.xlsx")
    targetwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A").Value = open_time 
    targetwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "A").Value = user_name
    targetwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "A").Value = file_name
    targetwb.Save
    targetwb.Close
End Sub
```

You can get the `last row number` of Monitor file and then append the new data. For security, you can add `password protection` to macro for each file so that nobody will be able to change your code.